# Low update rate on robot_localization

Tags: navigation, raspberrypi, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS kinetic, Raspbian  9.4 (Stretch) on a Raspberry Pi 3. I am equipping  a miniature vehicle (similar to the image below, image from google) for autonomous driving.

[image: image description]

So far my I have an IMU and encoders installed, and I am attempting to fuse the sensors with robot_localization ekf. The outputs of robot localization are actually close to the expected position/orientation, but the rate is unusable low and slow to converge as a consequence. Here is the output from rostopic hz.

```
note@pc:~$ rostopic hz odometry/filtered
subscribed to [/odometry/filtered]
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.290
    min: 3.444s max: 3.444s std dev: 0.00000s window: 2
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.264
    min: 3.444s max: 4.122s std dev: 0.33911s window: 3
[..]
```

The publish rates for the TF transforms is higher than 50Hz (image below), and robot_localization is set up to publish the odom->base_link transform.
[image: image description]

The same goes for the topics which robot_localization are subscribed to (below). Outputs from rqt.

[image: image description]

The configuration file for robot_localization is as shown below. I have played with frequency and sensor_timeout parameters, but I did not experiment much with the covariance matrices, as I expect to see performance changes by modifying the covariances, and not the filter`s loop frequency (Is this assumption correct?).

```
      <node name="local"   pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node">

  <param name="frequency" value="100"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.02"/>
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="true"/>
  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="odom"/>
  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="transform_timeout" value="0"/>

  <param name="imu0" value="imu/data"/>
  <param name="odom0" value="enc/pos"/>

  <rosparam param="imu0_config">
      [false, false, true,
       true,  true,  true, 
       false, false, false,
       true, true, true,
       true, true, true]
      </rosparam>

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">
      [true, true, true,
       false, false, false,
       false, false, false,
       false, false, true,
       false, false, false]
      </rosparam>

  <param name="imu0_queue_size"  value="10"/>
  <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>

  <param name="imu0_differential"  value="false"/>
  <param name="odom0_differential" value="false"/>

  <param name="imu0_relative"  value="false"/>
  <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>

  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration"  value="true"/>

  <rosparam param="initial_state">[0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                                0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                                0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                                0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
                            0.0,  0.0,  0.0]</rosparam>

  <param name="publish_tf"  value="true"/>

  <param name="publish_acceleration"  value="false"/>
  <param name="print_diagnostics"  value="true"/>

  </node>
```

Anyone would have insight on what I am missing?/ How can I get a higher update rate from robot_localization?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310785/low-update-rate-on-robot_localization/) by [hyori](https://answers.ros.org/users/39036/hyori/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2018-12-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-01-29**:
Please include a sample sensor message from every sensor input. My guess is that there's an issue with covariance matrices somewhere, but I can't say without more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At this point I have strong indications that it is all about the actual processing capacity of the Raspberry Pi. Basically what I have done is to move the localization node to another board (Nvidia TX2), while keeping the other nodes on the Raspberry Pi. In that setup I could get 80+ Hz update rate.

Furthermore, when used top to show cpu usage, it was pretty high.
[image: image description]

After the migration of robot_localization to TX2:
[image: image description]

I would be glad to hear from other Raspberry Pi users if anyone has faced a similar problem, and if they could actually have robot_localization running alongside various other nodes.

Here is a sample of IMU data:

```
    ---
    header:
      seq: 4516
      stamp: 
        secs: 1548832661
        nsecs: 383944034
      frame_id: "imu_base"
    orientation: 
      x: -0.00143707386235
      y: -0.0112244264823
      z: -0.349196171157
      w: 0.93698131311
    orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    angular_velocity: 
      x: 0.000330710783601
      y: -2.22474336624e-05
      z: 0.00118492916226
    angular_velocity_covariance: [0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03]
    linear_acceleration: 
      x: 0.222736816406
      y: 0.0502954101563
      z: 10.1836230469
    linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]
    ---
```

Here is a sample of Odometry Data:

---

```
header: 
  seq: 293
  stamp: 
    secs: 1548832850
    nsecs: 747138977
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -6.18503931136e-05
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.00011245525997
      w: 0.999999993677
  covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

[EDIT]

I have compiled robot_localization by adding the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo` parameter, and by doing so I got a reduction of cpu usage from 80% to 30-some% on `robot_localization`. The update rates are up too. I could actually do away with the TX2 now. Picture of the current state of the system:
[image: image description]

Thank you for the suggestions.

---

Originally posted by [hyori](https://answers.ros.org/users/39036/hyori/) with karma: 46 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-30**:
Something to check: if you're compiling `robot_localization` from source, make sure to have enabled optimisations.

**Comment by [hyori](https://answers.ros.org/users/39036/hyori/) on 2019-01-30**:
I am actually building it from source. How can I enable optimizations? Something like this?:

```
catkin_make --pkg robot_localization -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O3"
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-30**:
I would use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo`.

**Comment by [hyori](https://answers.ros.org/users/39036/hyori/) on 2019-01-30**:
I will try it and post results here.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-01-30**:
Yeah, your input data looks fine. I have an Odroid U3, and my recollection is that it runs fine on there. I'm interested to hear how you get on. I've had people complain about not even being able to build on a Raspberry Pi.

**Comment by [hyori](https://answers.ros.org/users/39036/hyori/) on 2019-01-30**:
Compiling with the optimization parameter seems to have done the trick.
Thank you for the suggestions.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-01-31**:
Just a further note: I think `RelWithDebInfo` results in the `-O2` flag being used, but if you go with `Release`, it uses `-O3`. You might get further CPU usage reduction in that case. From [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/71965/catkin-compiled-code-runs-3x-slower/).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-31**:
@Tom Moore: yes, that's correct. I always use `RelWithDebInfo` as I'm typically on the "developer side" and would like to have optimisations enabled but still be able to debug if needed.

Full `Release` would make that impossible.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-31**:
See [ros-infrastructure/bloom#327](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/327) for a related discussion btw.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-01-31**:
Yes, same. I only use `O3` for binaries and source builds that aren't meant to be used for dev. Curious as to how much of a difference it makes on this kind of hardware, though.